# SDO_UTIL.FROM_GEOJSON return geometry with 0 tolerance (only integers)

Tags: geojson, oracle-spatial

When we try to use SDO_UTIL.FROM_GEOJSON command in Oracle Database, the coordinates are integer. For example:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.FROM_GEOJSON('{"coordinates": [[[11.779,9.069],[15.83,9.194],[20.816,9.348],[21.111,5.658],[15.83,5.312],[10.86,4.986],[11.779,9.069]]], "type": "Polygon"}', NULL, 1001294499) FROM dual;
```

will return

```
[2003, 1001294499, [null, null, null], [1,1 003,1], [11,9,15,9,20,9,21,5,15,5,10,4,11,9]]
```

but I need:

```
[2003, 1001294499, [null, null, null], [1,1 003,1], [11.779,9.069,15.83,9.194,20.816,9.348,21.111,5.658,15.83,5.312,10.86,4.986,11.779,9.069]]
```

Also we tried example command from the internet, but there is the same result:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.from_geojson('{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -0.15380859375,
      51.50532341149335
    ]
  }') FROM dual;
```

Result:
`[2001, 4326, [0, 51, null], [NULL], [NULL]]`
What I need to do to fix that problem?

Comment: It would be better to give explicit links instead of "command from the internet", for example https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/geojson-data-support-19c.

Comment: @user30184 thanks, I thought that I can't use external links. That's it

Comment: If you select SDO_GEOMETRY from some spatial table, what coordinate precision do you get then?

Comment: @user30184 If I add row manually without from_geojson function, everything will be ok:
`[2003, 1001294499, [null, null, null], [1,1 003,1], [17 210,2347111632,14 246,3238079772,17 210,2347111632,14 215,8698422277,17 266,5864761123,14 224,1006437816,17 253,4240200658,14 246,3238079772,17 210,2347111632,14 246,3238079772]]`. There is an example with another data from database

Comment: And if you insert the geometry with from_geojson function into a table the coordinates get really truncated?

Comment: You seem to use a locale that is using comma as a decimal separator. I bet that's making the trouble. Try to change your locale to LANG=en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @user30184 Sounds interesting. I'll ask a question about that and will return with the answer, thanks.

Comment: @user30184, Yes, we have a win1251 locale BUT if I try to use command:
`SELECT SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POLYGON ((11.779 9.069, 15.83 9.194, 20.816 9.348, 21.111 5.658, 15.83 5.312, 10.86 4.986, 11.779 9.069))') FROM dual;
`, I get a normal result:
`[2003, null, [null, null, null], [1,1 003,1], [11,779,9,069,15,83,9,194,20,816,9,348,21,111,5,658,15,83,5,312,10,86,4,986,11,779,9,069]]`
Looks strange

Comment: What happens with from_geojson if you edit your GeoJSON strings and change points to commas? That's not valid GeoJSON but should be OK for testing the hypothesis.

Comment: @user30184 I will get an error ORA-13050.

Comment: @user30184, yes, your comment was correct. I did `alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. ';`, and function `from_geojson` returned correct answer

Comment: Great. Write that as an answer.

Comment: I would also consider to contact Oracle because this does feel like a bug. Unfortunately it is not as easy to create a bug report as in the open source world https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599961/where-is-the-oracle-bug-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS, and our locale that used comma as a decimal separator. After changing that separator by the command:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. ';
```

, the problem was fixed.