GeoJSON file creation from Oracle Spatial Code
Can we create GeoJSON file from below oracle spatial code:
CREATE TABLE buildings_3d (
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(100),
geom MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
);

INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
VALUES (
'buildings_3d',
'geom',
MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 0, 50, 0.005),
    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 0, 50, 0.005),
    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Z', 0, 50, 0.005)
),
32618
);


INSERT INTO buildings_3d (id, name, geom) VALUES (
1,
'Building 1',
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(
    3003,
    32618,
    NULL,
    MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1),
    MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 5, 0, 10, 5)
)
);

INSERT INTO buildings_3d (id, name, geom) VALUES (
2,
'Building 2',
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(
    3003,
    32618,
    NULL,
    MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1),
    MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(20, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 30, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10)
)
);


Did you try SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON?

an example of SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427467/sdo-util-from-geojson-return-geometry-with-0-tolerance-only-integers
